# How to take multiple photos using SwiftUI and UIImagePickerController

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a working implementation of SwiftUI + Camera using `UIImagePickerController`, but I am having trouble reloading the camera again after I take a photo (so i can take multiple pictures)

What happens is that after I take a picture, I get the "Retake/Use Photo". I select "Use Photo", and the delegate methods get called and I can grab the photo, great.  After that however, the View remains the same, still showing a still image with the "Retake/Use Photo" buttons

How can I trigger an update so I get the Camera again, with the desire being: Show Camera, Hit Button, select "Use Photo", then the camera shows again

```swift
// SampleQuestion.swift

import SwiftUI

struct SampleQuestion: View {

    @State var photos: [UIImage] = []

    var body: some View {
        return VStack{

            CameraViewIntegratedController(userPhotos: $photos)
                .frame(width: 400, height: 400)

        }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)

    }
}
```

```
// CameraViewIntegratedController
import SwiftUI
import UIKit


struct CameraViewIntegratedController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    @Binding var userPhotos: [UIImage]

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CameraViewIntegratedController>) -> UIImagePickerController {

        let vc = UIImagePickerController()
                   vc.sourceType = .camera
                   vc.allowsEditing = true
                   vc.delegate = context.coordinator
        return vc
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
            var parent: CameraViewIntegratedController

            init(_ imagePickerController: CameraViewIntegratedController) {
                self.parent = imagePickerController
            }

            func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {                
                guard let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else {
                    print("No image found")
                    return
                }
                print("Image Taken Successfully, with size \(image.size)")
                parent.userPhotos.append(image)

            }
    }
}
```

Ideally with after `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` I can reinitialize the camera. Or perhaps its on the SwiftUI side working with `@State` ?

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can't. The UIImagePickerController is one shot and done. I believe you're supposed to call dismiss at the end of the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo delegate.

Comment: @jkusachi is correct on both counts. In `UIKit` you only get *one* pick, be it from the PhotoLibrary or Camera, and in both delegate methods you dismiss. Be careful about "dismissing" in your SwiftUI app - I set a second variable `showPicker` as a `Bool` and in my `ContentView` either display the picker or the actual view based on it, along with setting it back to false in the delegate methods. There are third party pickers that allow for multiple selections, but if you want to use the "stock Apple app, I say hope that *eventually* they give us a `SwiftUI` picker that has these features.

Comment: Just as an FYI, I wanted to thank you for this question, and the best way was the upvote. The code you posted greatly helped me with my `UIImagePIckerController` in `SwiftUI`, which beta 4 broke. I was passing state variables into my `Coordinator` and while that worked in beta 3, they didn't after that. While I'm not new to programming, be it on mainframes, mobile, top-down, or OOP, I know *just* enough reactive programming to be dangerous. I like what your code taught me.

Comment: Thank you so much @don and @dfd for your help.  @dfd you are most certainly welcome for the code snippet, I'm happy I was able to help! 

It looks like I'll need to start dabbling with `AVFoundation` to achieve the multi picture taking functionality.   Looks like I got another challenge on my hands!

Comment: You could try .takePicture()  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/1619160-takepicture ```Use this method in conjunction with a custom overlay view to initiate the programmatic capture of a still image. This supports taking more than one picture without leaving the interface, but requires that you hide the default image picker controls.```

Comment: The following code crashes for me. As I simply want to open imagePickerController